# Positioning Radio buttons in Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[A screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbl9h.png)

I`m using bootstrap to create an image radio button, and I'm trying to position the radio button on the right corner of the image, tried absolute positioning but its not working, maybe I'm just missing something.

https://codepen.io/jhongeric/pen/eYNrgPP

```css
div {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio image-checkbox">
  <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input myinput" id="ck2a" name="ck2">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="ck2a">
      <img  src="https://via.placeholder.com/350

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="#" class="img-fluid">
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.custom-control-label::before{left:auto;right:0;}
```

https://codepen.io/vadivel-tlga/pen/NWqMdQX